# Search radius for some intermediate distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, proximity

ArcMap on my laptop runs very slowly. So it can take a long time for a near table to run.

Is it possible to use a search radius for some intermediate distance?

For example, the search radius only lets me specify up to 2000 metres, or up to 4000 metres.

My question is, is it possible to calculate distances in the range 2000-4000 metres?

Comment: Not with the existing near tool. You could write your own tool if you have ability in C#, C++ or VB.net that would; it is possible in python but would be *very* slow. Your best bet is to calculate your near table to 4k and then remove anything less than 2k from the results... as for making it faster, run in batches (one ArcCatalog for each core) by dividing the from points into groups. Esri is still a single thread program but it would be safe to run one Catalog per core and then append the tables when you're done. Beware the IDs won't match so you need to do something about that..

Comment: Possibly? Most geoprocessing tools honor selections, so if you run it with a select of only features in that range you might get what you want? But it isn't clear on how many feature classes you're trying to run generate near table on at once, how many features are in them, and what the near relationship you're looking at is.

Comment: My near features include 1770 different xy coordinates, and my input feature is over 60,000 xy coordinates for each year. And I have to do it by year, for 10 years. So calculating every distance is heavy duty. But thank you for your comments, hopefully I figure something out.

Comment: Rather than looking at ranges, I would break up the input features into smaller groups. Either by selection before running GNT or actually splitting up the files. Either way, for one year it's still around 106 million calcs or more than a billion for the whole thing. It's going to take some time. 64 bit background processing if available might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out-of-the-box ArcGIS for Desktop, the only way that I think you can do this is by running the analysis using 4,000 metres and then deleting/unselecting from the output table those with distances less than 2,000 metres.

Even if a programmatic solution can be developed to ignore rather than write the < 2,000 metre distances and to do that with markedly better performance than you currently achieve, I think the expense will be far more than purchasing more RAM or a better laptop.